# Difference between this.$parent.$emit and this.$emit

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When we need a custom component to emit an event in [VueTable2](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2), we must use:

```
this.$parent.$emit('myCustomEvent')

// instead of
this.$emit('myCustomEvent')
```

[This thread](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2/issues/21#issuecomment-262014205) tells us more about this aspect.

I used to run `this.$emit()` when I had to trigger an event. I was wondering what are the main differences between the two of them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`this.$emit` dispatches an event to its parent component.

`this.$parent` gives you a reference to the parent component.

As you might have guessed, `this.$parent.$emit` will make the parent dispatch the event to its parent.

Comment: Ho I see now! Thanks a lot Kira!